# What does $\frac{X_n}n$ converge to in distribution for $X_n \sim \chi^2_n$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

### Problem

I have been working through a probability question, where I am supposed to show that the following claim is **not** true. I believe I am supposed to use the Weak Law of Large Numbers in order to induce a contradiction, however, I'm not sure how to make progress here.

> **Claim:** For $X_n$ following the Chi Square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges in distribution to $X$ with $P(X=0)=1$. We want to show that this claim is false.

### Attempt

As $X_n$ follows the Chi Square distribution, we know that $$X_n=Z_1^2+Z_2^2+\cdots+Z_n^2$$ where each $Z_i$ follows the standard normal distribution.

I don't think each $X_i$ will be independent because $$X_i=X_{i-1}+Z_i^2$$ However, without assuming independence, I'm completely unsure of how to to proceed from here.

If we then assume independence, then the Weak Law of Large Numbers states:

> **Weak Law of Large Numbers:** for independent $X_1,  X_2, X_3$... with common mean and variance, then for all $\epsilon >0$, the probability $$P \Big{(} \Bigl{|} \frac{\sum_{1}^nX_k}{n}-\mu \Bigl{|} \ge \epsilon \Big{)} \rightarrow 0$$ $$\text{or alternatively}$$ $$P \big{(}\bigl{|}X_n-X \bigl{|} \ge \epsilon \big{)} \rightarrow 0$$

We can rewrite $$P\big{(}\bigl{|}X_n-X \bigl{|} \ge \epsilon \big{)} = P \big{(} \bigl{|}X_n \bigl{|} \ge \epsilon \big{)}$$ as $X=0$ with probability $1$.

---

I am unsure of how to proceed from here (or if what I have done is correct). I would be grateful for any further guidance as I am not sure if my assumption of independence is correct.

Comment: Apply law of large numbers to the independent summands $Z_i^2$

Comment: @YuvalPeres Thanks, I seem to have made some progress, but I’m not entirely sure how this helps with getting to the final answer. I now have that $P($ $\bigl{|}$ $\frac{X_n}{n}-1$ $\bigl{|} \ge \epsilon)$ $\rightarrow 0$. I don’t see any immediate contradiction here, however.

Comment: You have shown that $X_n/n\to1$ in probability. Recall that convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n\sim \sum^n_{k=1}Z^2_k$ where $(Z_k:k\in\mathbb{N})$ is an i.i.d. sequence with $Z_1\sim \operatorname{N}(0;1)$. As Yuval Peres suggested in his comment, by the strong law of large numbers

$$\frac{X_n}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}E[Z^2_1]=1\qquad\text{$\mathbb{P}$-a.s. and in $L_1(\mathbb{P})$}$$

Consequently $X_n/n$ converges in distribution to the Dirac mass measure $\delta_1$ at $1$, that is, for any bounded continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $$E[f(X_n/n)]\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}E[f(1)]=\int f(x)\,\delta_1(dx)$$